# ShaderMaterial fog parameter does not work

Tags: three.js

I'm having troubles enabling scene Fog in `THREE.ShaderMaterial`. Currently the fog only affects other geometries, but the Skydome that is created using THREE.ShaderMaterial, is unaffected by the fog.

There appears to be a boolean `fog` parameter in ShaderMaterial, which apparently should be set to true to use scene fog. Using it results in `uniforms.fogColor is undefined` errors however. The error happens at `WebGLRenderer` function `refreshUniformsFog`.

Is it a bug or am I using the parameter wrong?

Test case based on webgl_materials_lightmap.html example here: http://jsfiddle.net/HXhb4/
If you set fog to true in line 62 and run the test, you get the errors. What I would like to happen is the skydome to be affected by the fog like a model or skydome created with normal MeshPhongMaterial.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to use fog with your custom `ShaderMaterial`, you need to be sure to specify the required fog `uniforms`. For example,

```
var uniforms = {
    topColor:    { type: "c", value: new THREE.Color( 0x0077ff ) },
    bottomColor: { type: "c", value: new THREE.Color( 0xffffff ) },
    offset:      { type: "f", value: 33 },
    exponent:    { type: "f", value: 0.6 },
    fogColor:    { type: "c", value: scene.fog.color },
    fogNear:     { type: "f", value: scene.fog.near },
    fogFar:      { type: "f", value: scene.fog.far }
}

var skyMat = new THREE.ShaderMaterial( {
    vertexShader: vertexShader,
    fragmentShader: fragmentShader,
    uniforms: uniforms,
    side: THREE.BackSide,
    fog: true
} );
```

Also specify `fogDensity` if you decide to use it. You will also have to incorporate the fog logic into your shader.

three.js r.59

Comment: Thank you very much, this makes all kinds of sense! Including fog logic was very easy, just needed to include `THREE.ShaderChunk.fog_pars_fragment` and `THREE.ShaderChunk.fog_fragment` in the shaders.

Comment: I would like to do the same thing mentioned here, however I have no experience writing shaders. Any chance you or someone else could upload some code for how the shader logic was added to make this answer work? Thanks!

Comment: @Brannon please check my answer below with a code example

Answer (score 2):

In the accepted answer WestLangley mentioned:

> You will also have to incorporate the fog logic into your shader.

I figured out how to do that by reading the example [NormalDisplacementShader.js](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/js/shaders/NormalDisplacementShader.js). Here are the steps:

1. Write your shader in an external .js file
2. Add the UniformsLib
3. Add the ShaderChunks
4. In the fragment shader, declare `vec3 outgoingLight`
5. Use `outgoingLight` in your output `gl_FragColor`

Example below:

```
THREE.YourCustomShader = {

uniforms: THREE.UniformsUtils.merge( [

    THREE.UniformsLib[ "fog" ],

    {

    "someCustomUniform" : { type: 'f', value: 1.0 }

    }

] ),

fragmentShader: [

    "varying float someCustomVarying;",

    THREE.ShaderChunk[ "common" ],
    THREE.ShaderChunk[ "fog_pars_fragment" ],

    "void main() {",

        "vec3 outgoingLight = vec3( 0.0 );",

        THREE.ShaderChunk[ "fog_fragment" ],

        "gl_FragColor = vec4(outgoingLight, 1.0);",

    "}"

].join("\n"),

vertexShader: [

    "uniform float someCustomUniform;",

    "varying float someCustomVarying;",

    "void main() {",

        "someCustomVarying = 1.0 * someCustomUniform;",

        "gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0 );",

    "}"

].join("\n")

};
```

Comment: I am trying to follow your example except I use a texture like this..."gl_FragColor = texture2D(glowTexture, vUv);"....how would I apply the outgoingLight to it?