# ThreeJS ObjectLoader- cannot read property 'fog' of undefined

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am using ThreeJS to load a scene like so:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var scene = new THREE.ObjectLoader().load("scene.js");
    var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );
    var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    var fly = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera);
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
    document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

   var gui = new dat.GUI();
gui.add(controls, 'rotationSpeed',0,100);
    camera.position.z = 5;
    camera.position.z = 32;
    function render() {
        requestAnimationFrame( render );
        renderer.render( scene, camera );
    }
    render();
});
    var controls = new function() {
            this.rotationSpeed = 0.02;
            this.bouncingSpeed = 0.03;
    };
```

and here's the scene (Exported from the ThreeJS editor): http://www.codepixl.net/experiments/threejs/scene.js
But when I try to load the scene: It repeatedly throws cannot read property 'fog' of undefined and undefined is not a function at me. What's happening? What should happen:

Comment: Could this be related?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17757391

Comment: @ScottMcDermid The thing is though, my scene doesn't have fog in it.

Comment: `fog` appears to be a property of `scene`. Are you sure `scene` is being loaded properly? Does `scene.js` exist?

Comment: @ScottMcDermid I did check. It exists, but after closer inspection it has no 'fog' property. Do you know how I could add this manually and possible values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`load()` is asynchronous.
Instead of returning a value, it passes the result into a callback. Try something like this:

```
var loader = new ObjectLoader();
loader.load('scene.js', function(object) {
    scene.add(object); // load the object into your scene here
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realize it was asynchronous.