# How to add fog to texture in shader (THREE.JS R76)

Tags: three.js, glsl, shader

So firstly, I am aware of this post: [ShaderMaterial fog parameter does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17757391/shadermaterial-fog-parameter-does-not-work)

My question is a bit different...
I am trying to apply the fog in my three.js scene to a shader thats using a TEXTURE and I can't figure it out. My best guess as to what is supposed to go into the frag was:

resultingColor = mix(texture2D(glowTexture, vUv), fogColor, fogFactor);

This works when the texture2D part is just a normal color but as a texture it doesn't render.

```
THREE.glowShader = {

vertexShader: [

    `
    varying vec2 vUv;

    void main() {
        vUv = uv;
        gl_Position =  projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(position,1.0);
    }

    `

].join("\n"),

fragmentShader: [


    "uniform sampler2D glowTexture;",
    "varying vec2 vUv;",
    "uniform vec3 fogColor;",
    "uniform float fogNear;",
    "uniform float fogFar;",

    "void main() {",
         `
        vec4 resultingColor = texture2D(glowTexture, vUv);
        `,
        `#ifdef USE_FOG

            #ifdef USE_LOGDEPTHBUF_EXT

                float depth = gl_FragDepthEXT / gl_FragCoord.w;

            #else

                float depth = gl_FragCoord.z / gl_FragCoord.w;

            #endif

            #ifdef FOG_EXP2

                float fogFactor = whiteCompliment( exp2( - fogDensity * fogDensity * depth * depth * LOG2 ) );

            #else

                float fogFactor = smoothstep( fogNear, fogFar, depth );

            #endif`,

            // resultingColor = mix(texture2D(glowTexture, vUv), fogColor, fogFactor);

        `#endif`,
        "gl_FragColor = resultingColor;",
    "}"



].join("\n")
```

}

Comment: You can see what `THREE.ShaderChunk[ "fog_fragment" ]` is doing by looking at the [SOURCE](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/r76/src/renderers/shaders/ShaderChunk/fog_fragment.glsl)

Comment: ......resultingColor = mix( color, fogColor, fogFactor );
            "gl_FragColor =  vec4( ambient * vec3( resultingColor ), 1.0 );"......
Works for plain color with fog but I still am not able to do it with a texture using the mix function.

Comment: Hard to help without seeing all your new code. Update your question

Comment: I've updated the code. The commented out section is my best guess...which doesn't work. It worked with a standard color so I figured it would work with a texture but nope :/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Here is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2pha/h83py9gu/) that shows a ShaderMaterial with a texture and red fog

```
<script id="vertexShader" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
    varying vec2 vUv;
    varying vec3 vPosition;
    void main( void ) {
      vUv = uv;
      vPosition = position;
      gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(position,1.0);
    }
  </script>

  <script id="fragmentShader" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
    varying vec2 vUv;
    uniform sampler2D texture;
    uniform vec3 fogColor;
    uniform float fogNear;
    uniform float fogFar;
    void main() {
      gl_FragColor = texture2D(texture, vUv);
      #ifdef USE_FOG
          #ifdef USE_LOGDEPTHBUF_EXT
              float depth = gl_FragDepthEXT / gl_FragCoord.w;
          #else
              float depth = gl_FragCoord.z / gl_FragCoord.w;
          #endif
          float fogFactor = smoothstep( fogNear, fogFar, depth );
          gl_FragColor.rgb = mix( gl_FragColor.rgb, fogColor, fogFactor );
      #endif
    }
  </script>
```

Here is a bit of how to create the material

```
var uniforms = {
    texture:     { type: "t", value: texture},
    fogColor:    { type: "c", value: scene.fog.color },
    fogNear:     { type: "f", value: scene.fog.near },
    fogFar:      { type: "f", value: scene.fog.far }
};
var vertexShader = document.getElementById('vertexShader').text;
var fragmentShader = document.getElementById('fragmentShader').text;
material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial(
  {
    uniforms : uniforms,
    vertexShader : vertexShader,
    fragmentShader : fragmentShader,
    fog: true
  }
);
```

Comment: The fog is a bit expensive for fps. Do you know of any way in the shader to make the performance a bit higher? Otherwise I think I will have to drop the polys.

Comment: Note that you can use chunk #includes to save a a bit of work (e.g. #include <fog_fragment> in the fragment shader main. I can put a full example in a separate answer if interested