# Three.js shader material with fog

Tags: three.js, shader, fog

i have a problem with Three.js and its fog. The fog itself is implemented in the Render function to increase the fog with the time. The problem is that the fires are set as meshes like in volumetricFire and dont disapear when the fog increases. is there a possibily to get this fixed?

i was reading the same problem in this
[ShaderMaterial fog parameter does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17757391/shadermaterial-fog-parameter-does-not-work) , but dont know how to work on that.